# Unix timestamp before 1970 (even before 1700), using PHP

Tags: php, timestamp

how can i work with dates before 01.01.1970?

i need to get first day of the month for dates from year 1700.

how can i achieve that?

thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you provide an example of input data and expected result?

Comment: Is this date in the Julian calendar or the Gregorian calendar?

Comment: You might be using an old version of PHP. PHP4 must die. Versions of PHP after 5.1 don't have that 1970 restriction. It's been changed since to 1901.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [`DateTime`](http://php.net/DateTime).

Example:

```
<?php
$d = new DateTime("1780-06-01");
echo $d->format("l"); //Thursday
```

You should, however, consider that the Gregorian Calendar was [adopted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_Calendar#Adoption) in different instants throughout the world.

Comment: `DateTime` is the future. +1. Note that you need PHP 5.3 to enjoy some of the `DateTime` goodness (Intervals, CreateFromFormat and such). If in doubt, the manual will tell you the required version

Comment: DateTime cannot go before 1901 in all case.
$date = new DateTime('1869-01-01 07:00:00');
echo $date->format('U'); << This works.
$date->setTimestamp(-3187208524);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); << This does not work!

Comment: @vee works here (5.5.9). Maybe you're using a 32-bit build of PHP? Try passing the timestamp as a float instead (`-3187208524.`).

Comment: @vee You cannot use Unix timestamps before 1970, it's not defined. If it works, it's coincident, the result may not be correct though. See my reply https://stackoverflow.com/a/69959602/15809

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [Zend Date](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.date.introduction.html) classes, or the older [PEAR Date](http://pear.php.net/package/Date/redirected) class

Answer (score 0):

> If the year is <1970 or the value is negative, the relationship is undefined.

-- *The Open Group, Single Unix Specification, Base definitions (4: General concepts)*

As you can see, it's not defined how Unix timestamps before 1970 would map to dates. It is only defined for later dates.

If you want to go to dates before 1970, you need to always work with actual dates, like ISO dates (`2008-12-31T23:59:59`). You can use `DateTime` class to represent any date you can think of but ever created it from a Unix timestamp or convert it to a Unix timestamp if the year is before 1970 as that will simply yield undefined results.