# convert date to time stamp by php

Tags: php, html, date, timestamp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unix timestamp before 1970 (even before 1700), using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232194/unix-timestamp-before-1970-even-before-1700-using-php)

as you know we have `date` element in HTML5,It can return something like it `1000-10-05`,now I need to make this as time stamp,I try to do it by `mktime()` but It doesn't return true value.
now How can I do that?

Comment: The `mktime` only supports down to 1970 in the past, not year 1000.

Comment: @JürgenThelen - The range of Unix timestamps is not hard-coded by design; it depends on the size of the integers supported by the specific platform.

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario: you're right. I'm still living in 32-bit world, I guess^^

Comment: @JürgenThelen - *Unsigned* 32-bit, to be precise ;-)

Comment: @JürgenThelen dude, you took his lame example too seriously.

Comment: Your question needs editing. First, because `date` is an input type, not an element, and second, because you don't show how you're trying to parse the value, or what your actual problem is (ie, whether you don't know how to parse at all, or if you're actually trying to parse dates from the middle ages).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
strtotime($yourHTML$DateString);
```

Answer (score 7):

`mktime()` is timestamp based. On 32 bit systems, timestamps can't reach dates that far back - a signed int can reach from ca. 1900 to 2038.

If you need to do operations with pre-1900 dates, consider using the [`DateTime` library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) instead, available in PHP 5.2 and newer. It works with 64-bit data internally and can manage *any* date.

Comment: CW'ing because this is of course a dupe - the urge to answer is so often stronger than the urge to think and look for an original!

Comment: @moein Just a note:- you will need PHP > 5.2 to use the DateTime library.

Comment: @vascowhite - if you're using anything older than 5.2 these days, you seriously need to consider upgrading. Even 5.2 is no longer supported. Versions older than that have been out of support for a *long* time by now and are likely to have security issues.

Comment: @Spudley I didn't say I was, but some people on shared hosting are.

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is not the timestamp range issue as discussed, try strtotime instead of mktime.

Comment: As I stated in my answer ... if you're using a year 1000 date that is outside of the range of a timestamp but it wasn't clear to me when I answered that it wasn't just a jotted off example.

Answer (score 1):

`strtotime('1000-10-05')` must do it. but it supports only 1970 and >