# PHP 01/01/1970 Issues with Date Fields

Tags: php, date, datetime, strtotime

I am extracting date from a string. Below is my code. I am getting `only January 1, 1970` at the end. Please help me to fix this. your help would be appreciated.

```
    $current = 'DATE OF : 23/03/1951 BENCH:';

    $DATEOF = preg_replace('/(.*)DATE OF (.*?)BENCH:(.*)/s', '$2', $current);

    if (!is_null($DATEOF)) {
        $oldDate = $DATEOF;
        $oldDateReplace = str_replace(array('!\s+!', '/^\s+/', '/\s+$/',':'), array('','','',''), trim($oldDate));

        $date = ''.$oldDateReplace.'';
        $timestamp = strtotime($date);
    if ($timestamp === FALSE) {
         $timestamp = strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $date));
     }
     echo $newDate = date("F j, Y",$newDateM);

    }else{$newDate = '';}

    // print this date only January 1, 1970 i want this date 23/03/1951
```

Comment: "Please fix this error", lol

Comment: nothing wrong in general, just `echo date("d/m/Y",$timestamp);` in last row.

Comment: Sorry Jordy i am Student not developer i want fix this script to the my project,

Comment: thank you i am add echo date("d/m/Y",$timestamp); but mitkosoft problem is  01/01/1970 returned show

Comment: i am wit for your response

Comment: Look at this, might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232194/unix-timestamp-before-1970-even-before-1700-using-php

Comment: thanks you  Epodax i am not under stent pleas provide fix code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP date conversion to strtotime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32499055/php-date-conversion-to-strtotime)

Comment: thank you  maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ i am get this type of error Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string ( 23/05/1951&lt;/p&gt; &lt;p&gt;) at position 0 (2): Unexpected character

Comment: Thank you  Uchiha problem not solved

Comment: Uchiha how to change date format m/d/Y [PHP date conversion to strtotime ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32499055/php-date-conversion-to-strtotime)

Comment: thank you Ryan Vincent pleas provide code

Comment: cant understand what is your problem in above code?

Comment: thank you Vinie proplem is Only Display 01/01/1970 this date

Comment: you are echoing two date which one giving

Comment: 23/03/1951 'echo $newDate = date("F j, Y",$newDateM);' this date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code

```
$current = 'DATE OF : 23/03/1951 BENCH:';

$DATEOF = preg_replace('/(.*)DATE OF (.*?)BENCH:(.*)/s', '$2', $current);

if (!is_null($DATEOF)) {
$oldDate = $DATEOF;
$oldDateReplace = str_replace(array('!\s+!', '/^\s+/', '/\s+$/',':'), array('','','',''), trim($oldDate));

$date = ''.$oldDateReplace.'';
$timestamp = strtotime($date);
if ($timestamp === FALSE) {
     $timestamp = strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $date));
}
   echo $newDateM = date("m/d/Y",$timestamp);
   echo $newDate = date("F j, Y",$timestamp);

}else{$newDate = '';}
```

Comment: 01/01/1970 January 1, 1970 Vinie same problem i will get vinie your are same code copy and past in answer.

Comment: I tested it on my system. Check carefully I replaced `$newDateM` from `$timestamp` in `$newDate = date("F j, Y",$newDateM);
`

Comment: sorry vinie but not display this date

Comment: Yes working perfectly but my site display error vinie i am watch it my script error before i sent it code.

Comment: any one fix another method